# Why global property in MVC Controller is still empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, properties, global

I have this code in my Controller:

```
    List<string> order = new List<string>();
    [Route("Reservations/Overview/Refresh/id")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult AddOrder(string id)
    {
        if(!order.Contains(id))order.Add(id);
        return Json($"ok", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [Route("Reservations/Overview/Check/id")]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Check(string id)
    {
        if (order.Contains(id))
        {
            order.Remove(id);
            return Json(true);
        }
        else return Json(false);
    }
```

Everything is working but my global order list is always empty. Why?

Comment: Both action methods will be called separately, then you will get an empty list for each call/request ... if you wanna do that this way, just make it static and shared with all app

Comment: But i don't prefer that unless you need to make it accessible over the current session, then use Session variable instead

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are not persisted across multiple requests to the controller.  You can persist them to a database, or store the orders in session:

```
Session["Orders"] = orders;
```

You have to store the updated list of orders to session every time you modify the list or data within the list in any way.  Session is per user; just be careful how much data you put in session if you do.  If you use a database, you need to persist the record change anytime a value changes on a record, or when creating a new record.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is stateless.  Each request instantiates a *new* instance of the controller class, which wouldn't reflect any changes made to class-level variables on a *previous* instance (which has long since been disposed) from a previous request.

Basically you need to persist your data somewhere.  There are a variety of places to do this:

- Session state
- Static values
- A database
- A cache mechanism
- On the page itself (posted back with form data)
- Cookies
- A file
- and so on...

Each option is going to have its pros and cons, depending on the full set of functionality you need.  Session state may be the simplest approach to get you started.  On the page itself may be considered more RESTful and, thus, more scalable/portable.  A database would be more secure than on the page itself because users can modify anything on the page.  Etc.

But the point remains regardless of which option you want... The data needs to be persisted (saved) somewhere in order to be able to read it again at a later time.

Comment: Oh thank you, i somehow missed that.. thanks for solutions